# Mapbox js lib for loading tiles

Tags: vector, mapbox, tiles, cesiumjs, mapbox-gl

Is there a lib outside of mapbox gl for loading the tiles of a giving bbox and zoom level?

i've created some tilesets and styles in Mapbox and want to load it in other viewers (cesium, google maps,...)
I only have min, max lonlat and a z-level and need

- to load the specific tiles at the abstraction for the z-level
- iterate over the features
- get the geometry of the features in wgs84

Answer (score 0):

[mapbox-gl-js](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js) is the native library for interacting with mapbox vector tiles - the linked docs show it is build on web-gl, like cesium.

Regarding other libraries:

Leaflet has plugins for showing your mapbox vector tiles - some listed on the site only work on older versions of Leaflet, some only newer.

Similarly, OpenLayers added support for vector tiles, and different examples out there work only with different versions of OpenLayers - their official site has two examples that work with the current version 3.20.

Esri is rolling out their vector tile implementation right now, and there are posts in esri forums from last year explaining specifically about how to utilize mapbox vector tiles using their javascript api.

All of those libraries let you do what you are asking - load the mapbox vector tiles, process features and attributes, and work in different projections.

**Edit:**  (can't post comments yet) - OK, your question says (cesium, google maps,...) so I wasn't sure what was implied by the ellipses.  I will add that at least one of the leaflet plugins, and some of the solutions I have seen out there in adapting vector tiles for openlayers or leaflet utilize the mapbox-gl-js library to load and parse vector tiles, then adapt the data for the viewer in question.  Obviously if you write a custom solution for cesium an approach like that is possible, and that both libraries are web-gl based is a positive thing.  However, I have not done it myself so no more to add.  I'm sure you googled 'mapbox cesium' so found things like the recent google post about incorporating MB tiles to cesium, and some built-in cesium classes related to mapbox.  All good places to start.

**Edit** Lastly, I'll say that you might want to be looking at the various libraries that are part of the mapbox vector tile ecosystem - so this library, for example, might be as close as you will get to what you want at present without requiring you to go down to the web-gl level for a custom solution:  [mapbox vector-tile-js](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-js)

Answer (score 0):

@csdev. Thanks.

Yes i know there are other implementations in other viewers (ol3, leflet). But i'm not searching for a viewer, only for a framework which service the logic for loading and unloading vector tiles by given bboxes. Because i need it especially for cesium.

I see that there is a possibility to combine ol3 and cesium (ol3-cesium). But i think i will lose at this point functionality of cesium.

Comment: i think this will be one part for reading features of a concret tile https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-js